# Media content working

Tags: python, css, django, html, media

So I'm trying to make a portfolio and trying to just test things locally but it's NOT using my media content.. I've really tried LOTS of stuff.. and I'm out of ideas.

The HTML generated is correct, since I used the W3C validator for that.
And the src it refers to is also correct: /media/css/foo.css

And I'm quite sure my media_URL in my settings.py is also corrent:

```
/media/
```

Now here is my settingsfile, HTML, CSS, views, URLS and filestructure

SETTINGS:

```
# Django settings for portfolio project.
import os 
gettext = lambda s: s
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'database.db'),                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "media")

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'blabla'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS= (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth', 
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n', 
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'portfolio_svn.urls'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates"),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'portfolio',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

HTML: base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>{% block page_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}base.css" />

    {% block head_extra %} {% endblock %}
    <!-- Enabling HTML5 tags for older IE browsers -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<header>
<h1>My portfolio</h1>
</header>

{% block nav %}
<nav id = "navigation">

</nav>
{% endblock %}


<section id = "content">

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
</section>



<footer>

</footer>

{% block includes %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

HTML index.html

```
{% extends "portfolio/base.html" %}

{% block page_title %}
Lime Design | Best web dev and design online
{% endblock %}

{% block head_extra %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/nav_port.css" />
{% endblock %}



{% block content %}

<nav id = "filter">

</nav>

<section id="container">
    <ul id="stage">
        {% for project in projecten %}
            <li data-tags="{{ project.disciplines }}">
                <img src="{{ project.overview_image }}" alt="{{ project.name }}" />
            </li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>    
</section>
{% endblock %}


{% block includes %}
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
<script src = "{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/script.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

CSS

```
body{
background-color: #151515;
}
```

view

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.template.context import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, Http404
from models import Medium, Client, Project


def index(request):
    projecten = Project.objects.all()  
    context = {'projecten': projecten}
    return render_to_response('portfolio/index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, context))
```

URLS:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from portfolio_svn.portfolio.models import Project
from portfolio_svn.portfolio.views import index
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^index', index),
    (r'^', index),
    (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

file structure

```
portfolio_svn
├── database.db
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── local_settings.py
├── local_settings.pyc
├── manage.py
├── media
│   ├── css
│   │   └── nav_port.css
│   ├── images
│   │   └── thumbmails
│   │       ├── 1.png
│   │       ├── 2.png
│   │       ├── 3.png
│   │       └── 4.png
│   └── js
│       ├── jquery.quicksand.js
│       └── script.js
├── portfolio
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── settings_backup_local.py
├── settings_backup_real.py
├── settings.py
├── settings.pyc
├── templates
│   └── portfolio
│       ├── base.html
│       └── index.html
├── urls.py
└── urls.pyc
```

I hope someone can help me pin-point the problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using the media for what the static is for, check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

In resume, the media folder is made for people uploading photos, files, etc.

the static folder is for css, js, images you use in your website.

if you are not loading your static folder into a separate server you can add this lines to your urls.py

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatters = patterns ......#do your patterns here

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

that way Django will mount the static files right away.

for django to be able to find this static files you should add to your settings.py this values:
    import os

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = (
    "portfolio/static/",
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = ( 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
     #... other context processors
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....#other apps
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

move that static folder to your app aplication (in this case portfolio) and execute

```
./manage.py collectstatic.
```

for what I can see it should work. (you should change the 'django.core.context_processors.media' for 'django.core.context_processors.static' btw)

P.D.: if you want to pass the request to your render_to_response you can use the render(request, 'portfolio/index.html') instead :)

Comment: So I have to put my static folder (different static folders then..) in the different app folders..? Isn't that a bit.. euhm, 'odd'?

I mean wouldn't it be more natural to make a /media/CSS-or-JS-or-.../files-or-subdirsforapps

And when doing collectstatic I get 'unknown command 'collectstatic' 'type manage.py help' for usage

Comment: oh I didn't check, you need to install the static app for collectstatic to work. And yes I understand your point of view, the good thing about having that folder in your app is that when you want to pass that app to another project you will only need to move it there and install it in the settings.py

Comment: I used: http://blog.bixly.com/post/4579203162/django-static-files + http://django-staticfiles.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#staticfiles-dirs to set up the static system (what you said didn't work yet..) but now for example, when I used (findstatic nav_port.css I get "No matching file found for..." which is odd since I know it's in there..

Comment: now I've added the django.contrib.staticfiles to my installed apps and I get "No module named static' apps.. while this should be included..

Comment: I added the steps to the answer to explain it better.
Are you sure you are using Django 1.3?

Comment: Hmmm I just did a version check and I think my django is at version 1.2.5 | I should probably update it..?

Comment: YESSSSSSSSS!!!! I finally got it to work! you're my hero <3 thank you sooo much for the extended help!

Comment: It would be perfect if we could sent this to chat but It doesn't let us since you don't have enough reputation :s. If you have any other question don't hesitate to ask, we can always help in stackoverflow

Comment: Perhaps by email then? if youd on't mind? dominique.at.complex"AT"hotmail"DOT"COM that's my 'spam' mail, if you mail me there, I'll contact you with my normal mail ^^